# play FLAC from resources of web server in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio, flac

I'm running an apache2 website where you are able to upload lossless files including .wav and .flac. wav files works right away while flac is not supported. So I was wondering if there is any way to play these flac files with some help of JavaScript?

Here is what happends:

1. Click button to choose file.
2. Once chosen, it will automaticly send post request to a PHP file i named "flacuploader.php"

   ```
   <form action="flacuploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="choose_file">
           <span style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Lossless File...</span>
           <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="file" name="fileToUpload" accept=".flac,.wav,.aiff,.iff,.riff" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();">
       </div>
   </form>
   ```
3. Then flacuploader.php saves the post request to a folder "/lossless" with no changes to the file.
4. Now here is the problem. How do I play it?

I search around and came across this: [Flac.js - GitHub](https://github.com/audiocogs/flac.js) and [Playing a FLAC file over WebRTC with SIP.js and Flac.js](https://www.wakamoleguy.com/2014/flac-over-webrtc-with-sipjs/).
But I think those sources missed my question because I simply want to decode it to a playable file, or have javascript to do the job.

I have a file in /lossless called test.flac, and I simply want to be able to play that file in PHP/html. It is not meant to be full quality, but rather a preview of the upload. But the original file will still be stored as it is.

I tried putting this in the flacuploader.php:

```
<script src="js/aurora.js"></script>
<script src="js/flac.js"></script>
<script src="js/sip.js"></script>

<script>
    var player = AV.Player.fromFile("lossless/test.flac");
    player.play();
</script>
```

And so it wouldn't play the sound.

Anything will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `sip.js` file if you only want to play the file in the browser.

To simply play a file from a URL you can use the `fromURL` method to create your player.

```
var player = AV.Player.fromURL(url);
```

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/28ppk74s/) example showing how that works.

**HTML**

```
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
var pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pause');
var url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/Debussy_-_Pour_les_accords.flac"
var player = AV.Player.fromURL(url);

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  player.play()
})

pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  player.pause()
})
```

You could also use the `FileReader` API with the `readAsArrayBuffer` method on the reader to pass the result to `AV.Player.fromBuffer`.

Here the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6yenx6vc/) for that example.

( Sorry, the examples for some reason did not work in SO snippets, so i have to use JSFiddle )

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<button>play</button>
```

**CSS**

```
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
button {
  display: none
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $fileInput = $('#file-input');
var $btn = $('button');
var isPlaying = false;
var player;

function readFile(e) {
  if(window.FileReader) {
    var file  = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (file && file.type.match('audio/flac')) {
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    } else {
      console.log('Please add a flac file.')
    }
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      player = AV.Player.fromBuffer(reader.result)
      $btn.show()
      $btn.on('click', function() {
        if(isPlaying) {
          player.pause();
          isPlaying = false;
          this.textContent = 'play'
        } else {
          player.play();
          isPlaying = true;
          this.textContent = 'pause'
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

$fileInput.on('change', readFile)
```

Comment: hmm. In the second example, it seams like the audio is being played locally which is ok. But how can I specify the file being chosen instead of having a window pop up to choose the file?
I'm sure I can pass the location of the FLAC being uploaded from one PHP to another, so that the server uses minimal bandwidth.

Comment: ahh wait a sec.. I got it working, but that was from the first example. Reason was that I couldn't stream a file from my website to jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Sure, just use the `fromURL` method after the upload has finished. The location to the uploaded file is just a URL.