# How to have Javascript download a specific media file type?

Tags: javascript, mp4, file-type, flac

The following script is built to one-click download .mp4 audio files that have just played in a player. The only problem is that the version of the player I use provides audio in lossless .flac format, so it doesn't do anything when I use it. How might I change it so that it outputs flac instead of just nothing?

I'm totally clueless.

```
(function() { 
  var songs = document.getElementsByTagName('video'); 
  for(var i = 0 ; i < songs.length ; i++ ) { 
    if(songs[i].getAttribute("jw-played") == "") {
      window.open(songs[i]["src"]); 
    } 
  } 
}) ();
```

When I use it with the version of the player that's using .mp4 audio, it scrapes just fine. I'm not sure how to change it to make it see .flac files. It just does nothing when I use it.

Comment: You can add download attribute in anchor tag. didnt work?

Comment: Have you done some research? Start you research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336909/play-flac-from-resources-of-web-server-in-html).

Comment: As i see it has nothing to do with file types, it just opens the url specified in src. Also as you mentioned there are no download functions bi think. Try to create anchor with download attribute and trigger click or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [play FLAC from resources of web server in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336909/play-flac-from-resources-of-web-server-in-html)